# Передача нужного URL на WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

У меня есть несколько кнопок находящихся на фрагменте и один WebView находящийся на активити. Функция этих кнопок в моём представлении в том чтобы открывать соответствующий им URL-адрес. Не создавать же мне для каждого адреса отдельную активити с WebView? Как обойтись одной, просто передавая на WebView нужный адрес после клика?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В методе *onCreate()* активити пишем:

```
   final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    webView.loadUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android");
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    webView.loadUrl("https://github.com");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: А если WebView и кнопки на разных активити? К тому же кнопки находятся на фрагменте.

Comment: Где-то сохраните нужный выбор (например в Prefereces) и установите правильный url в onResume() активити.

Comment: Создайте активити/фраомент с webView и из любого места передавайте любую ссылку как bundle через put extra. И там ее устанавливайте. Intent.put extra  закидываем и там отлавливаем.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String my_url = "example.com";

intent.putExtra("URL", my_url);
```

А в webView активити

```
    Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bundle bd = intent.getExtras(); if(bd != null) { String url = bd.get("URL"); webView.load(url); }
```